# Why Sharepoint 2013 keeps asking me to log in?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have an intranet web page.When I entered to the web page,it ask me to log in. When I put my credentials he lets me in but when inside he asks me again and again and again. If I click another section it will ask me again too.

I have tried adding the web page to trusted sites,credential manager on windows. I think this is not case since I have a qa site and doesn,t happens.

This only happens to this site because I have more sites on the server and they work as expected.

I have multiple sub sites on the page I don't know if this maybe related.

How can I solve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: is this solved?

Answer (score 1):

Refresh your browser cache/ passwords..
If the page you are trying to access has some code/webpart which tries to access a resource to which you dont have access, then it can give this issue.